# Rx-Java, calling parallel async after a sync

Tags: rx-java

I have few simple java classes that looks like this:

```
 public class Parent {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public List<String> childIds;
 }

 private class Child {
    public String id;
    public String name;
 }

 private class Output {
    public String name;
    public List<String> childNames;
 }
```

I want to send rx-java a list of parent IDs.  for each parent Id, rx needs to get the parent object, then for each child id in the parent object, get the child objects.  Finally, fill up the output object and return it.

The part I am having problems with is that the calls to get the child objects need to be done in parallel.  Here is what I have so far.  I use the collect function to add the children into the output (the children are gotten using Async.from).  This seems pretty complicated for what I'm trying to do.  Is this the best way to do it, or is there some better way?

```
  private class ToOutput implements Func1<Parent, Observable<Output>> {
    private Observable<Child> getChildren(Parent p) {
      Observable<String> childIds = Observable.from(p.childIds);
      return childIds.flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Child>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<Child> call(String sku) {
          return Async.fromCallable(new ToChild(sku), Schedulers.io());
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Output> call(final Parent p) {

      Func0<Output> initialState = new Func0<Output>() {
        @Override
        public Output call() {
          final Output output = new Output();
          output.name = p.name;
          output.childNames = new ArrayList<String>();
          return output;
        }
      };

      Observable<Child> oChildren = getChildren(p);
      Observable<Output> output = oChildren.collect(initialState, new Action2<Output, Child>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Output output, Child child) {
          output.childNames.add(child.name);
        }
      });
      return output;
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test1() throws Exception {
    Observable<String> ids = Observable.just("1", "2", "3");
    Observable<Parent> parents = getParent(ids);
    Observable<Output> output = parents.flatMap(new ToOutput());
    ... do something with output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Async.fromCallable`, you could define a method

```java
Observable<Child> getChild(String childId)
```

which basically does what `ToChild.call` currently does.

Then in the `flatMap`, you can use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to get the parallelism:

```java
Observable<Child> getChildren(Parent p) {
    return Observable.from(p.childIds)
        .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Child>>() {
            public Observable<Child> call(String childId) {
                return getChild(childId).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
            }
        });
}
```

And in `ToOutput`, you could benefit from the `toList()` operator instead of implementing it yourself:

```java
class ToOutput implements Func1<Parent, Observable<Output>> {
    public Observable<Output> call(final Parent p) {
        return getChildren(p)
            .map(new Func1<Child, String>() {
                public String call(Child c) {
                    return c.name;
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .map(new Func1<List<String>, Output>() {
                public Output call(List<String> l) {
                    return new Output(p.name, l);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That look much better than my solution.